# Is /org/freedesktop/DBus accessible from a web browser?

Tags: chrome, d-bus, xubuntu, freedesktop, javascript

We have some homebrewn applications running in top of a Xubuntu 18.04 OS, communicating with each other using D-Bus. The UI part is run in a web browser and web socket is being used for the communication with the applications.

Our aim is to migrate every communication made to D-Bus, but I have tried accessing the `/org/freedesktop/DBus` from the chromium browser for testing purposes and had no luck. I used [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbus-native):

```
var dbus = require('dbus-native')
  var conn = dbus.createConnection()
  conn.message({
    path: '/org/freedesktop/DBus',
    destination: 'org.freedesktop.DBus',
    'interface': 'org.freedesktop.DBus',
    member: 'Hello',
    type: dbus.messageType.methodCall
  })
  conn.on('message', function (msg) { console.log(msg) })
```

And this is what I see in the browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: unknown bus address
    at createStream (index.js?26d9:22)
    at Object.createConnection (index.js?26d9:76)
```

This is what I see when running `dbus-monitor`, but I don't know if it can even be related to my connection attempt:

```
signal time=1626258028.185483 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.196 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.196"
signal time=1626258028.185641 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.196 serial=4 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.196"
method call time=1626258031.724118 sender=:1.195 -> destination=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit; interface=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit; member=UnInhibit
   uint32 39
method return time=1626258031.724440 sender=:1.27 -> destination=:1.195 serial=151 reply_serial=7
method call time=1626258031.724721 sender=:1.195 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=8 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=RemoveMatch
   string "type='signal', path='/org/freedesktop/DBus/Local',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Local', member='Disconnected'"
method return time=1626258031.724743 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.195 serial=7 reply_serial=8
signal time=1626258031.725311 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.195 serial=5 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.195"
signal time=1626258031.725517 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=339 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.195"
   string ":1.195"
   string ""
```

Is the freedesktop DBus accessible from the web browser or maybe do I need to make some tweak in the DBus daemon configuration to allow it? I'm kind of new to D-Bus.

Comment: You probably need https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html

Comment: @muru, do you mean running `dbus-monitor`? I've already used that and got the trace that I posted

Comment: Oh, sorry, copied the wrong link. I meant https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DFeet (from https://askubuntu.com/q/11453/158442)